# recurring paypal with preapproval adaptive payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have create rails application and implemented preapproval payment using [adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby) gem. I plan to use this as recurring payment.

this is my code for create preapproval:

```
ADAPTIVE_PAYMENT.build_preapproval({
  :cancelUrl => my_cancel_url,
  :currencyCode => "USD",
  :paymentPeriod => "DAILY",
  :returnUrl => my_return_url,
  :startingDate => DateTime.now.in_time_zone
})
```

and then I use this code to charge:

```
ADAPTIVE_PAYMENT.build_pay({
  :actionType => "PAY",
  :cancelUrl => my_cancel_url,
  :currencyCode => "USD",
  :feesPayer => "PRIMARYRECEIVER",
  :preapprovalKey => Preapproval_key,
  :receiverList => {
    :receiver => [{
      :amount => 100,
      :email => example@example.com,
      :primary => true},
      {
      :amount => $100,
      :email => example@example.com,
      :primary => false }
    ]
  },
  :returnUrl => my_return_url
})
```

How to make it automatically charged every day without execute the pay code again?

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure there is no automatic pay feature from paypals side. I know that you can setup how many monthly / weekly payments they are signing up for but I think thats just for the pre-approval agreement.

However, why dont you just setup a CRON job and let it take care of it for you? I was super nervous about doing this with paypal adaptive payments the first time but its actually saved me SO much time and its a lot more reliable than any human could be with its ability to send job reports after its done.